# Arcanist: Arc Land Exception

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I'm trying to arc land with arcanist but I'm getting the following exception:

```
[2021-07-23 08:44:49] EXCEPTION: (ConduitClientException) ERR-CONDUIT-CALL: <harbormaster.buildable.search> Conduit API method "harbormaster.buildable.search" does not exist. at [<arcanist>/src/conduit/ConduitFuture.php:70]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=76a2976fd9a4)
  #0 ConduitFuture::didReceiveResult(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:40]
  #1 Future::updateFuture() called at [<arcanist>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:35]
  #2 FutureProxy::isReady() called at [<arcanist>/src/conduit/ConduitSearchFuture.php:62]
  #3 ConduitSearchFuture::isReady() called at [<arcanist>/src/future/Future.php:63]
  #4 Future::updateFuture() called at [<arcanist>/src/future/FutureIterator.php:224]
  #5 FutureIterator::next() called at [<arcanist>/src/hardpoint/ArcanistHardpointEngine.php:215]
  #6 ArcanistHardpointEngine::updateFutures() called at [<arcanist>/src/hardpoint/ArcanistHardpointEngine.php:176]
  #7 ArcanistHardpointEngine::waitForRequests(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/runtime/ArcanistRuntime.php:858]
  #8 ArcanistRuntime::loadHardpoints(array, ArcanistHardpointRequestList) called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistWorkflow.php:2327]
  #9 ArcanistWorkflow::loadHardpoints(array, array) called at [<arcanist>/src/land/engine/ArcanistLandEngine.php:542]
  #10 ArcanistLandEngine::confirmBuilds(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/land/engine/ArcanistLandEngine.php:524]
  #11 ArcanistLandEngine::confirmRevisions(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/land/engine/ArcanistLandEngine.php:1220]
  #12 ArcanistLandEngine::execute() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistLandWorkflow.php:344]
  #13 ArcanistLandWorkflow::runWorkflow(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistWorkflow.php:227]
  #14 ArcanistWorkflow::executeWorkflow(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>/src/toolset/ArcanistPhutilWorkflow.php:21]
  #15 ArcanistPhutilWorkflow::execute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<arcanist>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:492]
  #16 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/runtime/ArcanistRuntime.php:171]
  #17 ArcanistRuntime::executeCore(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/runtime/ArcanistRuntime.php:37]
  #18 ArcanistRuntime::execute(array) called at [<arcanist>/support/init/init-arcanist.php:6]
  #19 require_once(string) called at [<arcanist>/bin/arc:10]
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?